# Setting map view extent dynamically in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, extents, draw-interaction, modify-interaction

Referring to the examples posted here https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html and https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/extent-interaction.html
in the former example, the `extent` is added to `View` object, while in the latter example, the `extent` is added to `Interaction`.

Now, i have the following `extent`:

```
const extent = get(proj).getExtent().slice();
extent[0] += extent[0];
extent[2] += extent[2];
```

and I would like to add it to the map object I have. The map object I have, has already `layers`, `traget` and `view` properties set.
What I want to do is, to modify that map object and set or add to it the `extent` mentioned above.

I do not know whether should i add the `extent` to `View` or to `interaction`? I checked the official `openlayers API`  and for `interaction` there is a method called `setExtent` but there is no such one available for `View`! But according to the former link, the `extent` was set to `view`

Please clarify this confusion and please let me know how to achieve that.

**map Object**:

```
const map = new Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 4,
  }),
});
```

**update**

I would like to know how to set the extent to the view via a method.?
Because I have a class called MapBuilder and it has the following methods:

```
Getmap()
SetExtent()
```

The first method returns the map object as shown above. I want to implement the second method ‘setExtent()’.
How the implementation of it should look like please

Comment: There are many uses of extent in OpenLayers.  The `extent` option on the view constrains the view, the `extent` option on a layer restricts layer rendering, the `extent` option on a tile grid restricts tile requests.  What is the purpose of your extent?

Comment: @Mike thank you for the edifying info. However, I would like to use the ‘extent’ in the context of digitizing a polygon as shown in the formerly posted link.would please tell me what do mean by that the ‘extent’ will constraint the view when used on a ‘view’..

Comment: From the [docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html): _The extent that constrains the view, in other words, nothing outside of this extent can be visible on the map._

Comment: @Mike would you please have a look at the updated section posted

Comment: @TomazicM would you please have a look at the updated section posted

Comment: Where do these two classes come from? Any docs?

Comment: @TomazicM no I created it..it is encapsulates some functions like createMap(), setSource(),….etc…now I want to add SetExtent method but I do not how should I set the extent to the view object” as shown above” without having any method the sets the extent tot he view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since view object has no `.setExtent()` method, one possible solution would be to create new view with the desired extent and set map view to that view.

Code for function that sets map view extent dynamically could then be something like:

```
function setViewExtent(extent) {
  var view = new ol.View({extent: extent});
  view.fit(extent)
  map.setView(view);
}
```

Function would then be called like this:

```
var extentCoords = [
  [
    -768039,
    6536294
  ],
  [
    1114746,
    5326732
  ]
];

var extent = ol.extent.boundingExtent(extentCoords);
setViewExtent(extent);
```

Comment: would you please tell me how to get the current extent set to a view?i checked the map and view classes documents in the official ol-api but couldnt find any method like getExtent?

Comment: GIS SE site has policy of focused questions, which among other things means also one question per question. This is a separate question, so please post it as a new question.

Comment: hi, would you please have a look at this question please:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/471097/how-to-read-features-on-the-map-as-the-mouse-hovers-it